# Unable to connect to postgres installed as docker image in ubuntu vm in virtualbox from host psAdmin

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, postgresql

i installed postgres on ubuntu vm on using virtualbox the host is windows 10

```
umen@umen:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
2583c47b9879   postgres:14.5   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   27 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   umen-postgres-1
```

The network :
umen@umen:~$ ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d2:b3:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 84940sec preferred_lft 84940sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed2:b390/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:0b:76:ab:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-fb9123c510ce: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:b3:7c:dd:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-fb9123c510ce
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:b3ff:fe7c:dd85/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth24b752d@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-fb9123c510ce state UP group default
    link/ether 22:61:bb:76:68:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::2061:bbff:fe76:6883/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.5'
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: movies
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
```

The pgAdmin config from the host (windows)
[image]

I still getting no matter what i try :
[image]

port forwarding:
[image]

Comment: No need to guess what is happening, the server logs are available to you. They will surely contain the necessary information to fix this, though you may have to up the log level first.

Comment: nothing in the postgress logs